# Could I run tests in a dependency project by tag, as I run main projects in Playwright?

Tags: node.js, playwright, playwright-test

I would like to run a certain suit of tests. I have several projects, divided by flows, and one setup dependency project with preconditions.

I added a tag to tests names, that I need to run, also added the tag into the preconditions project, but again only in some necessary tests, because I don't need to run all preconditions.

As a result, dependency was run with all tests, independently of the tag, and the other tests from the main projects were run correctly, only with the tag.

Tried to run with the grep flag:
--grep=@tag

Comment: Please share the minimal reproducible code example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define multiple setup files in config based on conditions:

For example you have two types of tags , you may define two files  as globalSetupA & globalSetupB containing these two set of tests.

```
projects: [
    {
      name: 'setupA',
      testMatch: /globalA.setup\.ts/,
    },
    // {
    //   other project
    // }
  ]
});
```